# Cannot Select From JQuery Autocomplete Selection Options

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm working on this jQuery Autocomplete thing and I can't get the item selected from the result set to appear in the textbox after clicking on it.

As you can see, the code returns and item, i see the drop down. (I'd post a pic but i'm new and can't =/ )
but after I click on it, nothing happens: (Joe Blow goes away, not shown but result is just a 99 in the field)

here is my code:

```
var techNumber = $('#<%= txtTechNumber.ClientID %>');
        techNumber.autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Service/ServiceHelpdesk/") %>srvWebServiceRepository.asmx/FetchTechnicianList',
                    data: "{ 'techNumber':'" + request.term + "' }",
                    dataType: "json",
                    dataFilter: function(data) { return data; },
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data.d != null) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
                                return {
                                    label: highlight(item.TechNumber, request.term) + " - " + item.TechFirstName + " " + item.TechLastName,
                                    value: item.TechID
                                }
                            }))
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                    },
                    select: function(event, ui) {
                        techNumber.val(ui.item);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `ui.item`, use `ui.item.label` in your `select` handler. It probably wouldn't hurt to `preventDefault` the event either. Finally, make sure the definition for the `select` handler is inside the options object passed to the widget (previously it was in the AJAX options object):

```
var techNumber = $('#<%= txtTechNumber.ClientID %>');
        techNumber.autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Service/ServiceHelpdesk/") %>srvWebServiceRepository.asmx/FetchTechnicianList',
                    data: "{ 'techNumber':'" + request.term + "' }",
                    dataType: "json",
                    dataFilter: function(data) { return data; },
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data.d != null) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
                                return {
                                    label: highlight(item.TechNumber, request.term) + " - " + item.TechFirstName + " " + item.TechLastName,
                                    value: item.TechID
                                }
                            }))
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                techNumber.val(ui.item.label);
            }            
            minLength: 1
        });
```

Comment: Great! That was the problem, the select: function was in the wrong spot.  Once I moved it, it worked as it should've.  Thank you very much for the rapid reply.

Comment: Great post, this helped me meet a deadline! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This one is a generic Fix.

Add this on top of your function before calling .autocomplete

```
(function ($) {

    $(".ui-autocomplete-input").live("autocompleteopen", function () {
        var autocomplete = $(this).data("autocomplete"),
        menu = autocomplete.menu;

        if (!autocomplete.options.selectFirst) {
            return;
        }

        menu.activate($.Event({ type: "mouseenter" }), menu.element.children().first());
    });

} (jQuery));
```

And then inside the function just add a parameter `selectFirst: true` like :

```
$('#ctl00_PageBody_txtKeywords').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'getData.asmx/LoadData',
                selectFirst: true,
```

(P.S. Couldn't find the original reference, this must point to it http://bit.ly/INzcrv)